# Reading UTF-8 text file as UTF-16 in Java

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, utf-16

I am reading a UTF-8 encoded text file in my Java program as UTF-16 just to see what happens. I am getting output string containing only '?'. Could anyone please explain how the UTF-8 codepoints are getting converted to UTF-16 and why am I getting only '?' in my output.

**This is the code-**

```
public class MyUTF {

    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws IOException, FileNotFoundException
    {
        InputStream is=new FileInputStream("file1.txt");
        System.out.println(is.available());

        InputStreamReader isr=new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-16");
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(isr);
        System.out.println(br.readLine());
    }
}
```

If the file contains 'a' then I get '?' as output.
If it contains 'abc' then I get '??'.

Please explain this conversion from UTF-8 to UTF-16.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you surprised that it fails to read characters and instead gives you indicators of undefined inputs?

Comment: What you have done is similar to looking up English words in a French dictionary. No wonder, you get only garbage.

Comment: What's happening here follows directly from the structure and mapping of UTF-8 and UTF-16, so you really just need to go read up on both of those.

Comment: [On two occasions I have been asked, — "Pray, Mr. Babbage, if you put into the machine wrong figures, will the right answers come out?"…. I am not able rightly to apprehend the kind of confusion of ideas that could provoke such a question.](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Charles_Babbage)—Charles Babbage, 1864.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you see in your terminal depends on many factors:

- Is your platform little or big endian?
- Can your terminal display lots of characters or only a few?

If you are just seeing question marks, you probably have an old computer or a very hobbled terminal emulator.

I can tell you what I see on my Mac. My laptop is little endian. I made the file `file1.txt` contain `abc` then a new line. In other words, the four characters U+0061 U+0062 U+0063 U+000A. Now since UTF-8 is the default *encoding* my file contains 4 bytes:

```
61 62 63 0A
```

Please understand *A file only contains bytes. It does not contain characters.* (Sure there are tricks like sticking BOMs in the file to make the file’s intended encoding apparent, but really it is just a suggestion.)

Now when you read in that file as UTF-16, you *decoded* those four bytes into two characters:

```
U+6162
U+630A
```

When I run your program, it prints like this for me

```
慢挊
```

Now suppose I did not have the newline so the file had only three bytes. In this case

```
61 62 63
```

Now when I run your program I see

```
慢�
```

That is the character U+6162 as before, and then the replacement character because *you cannot decode the single byte 63 in UTF-16*. In UTF-16 characters are represented in either 2 or 4 bytes, never just 1. My terminal program shows replacement characters. I think yours just shows question marks.